# Understanding dataframe.shape df.shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am taking the udacity data analysis course and i am having trouble understanding an answer.

Have been asked to "create color array for red dataframe".

the answer is

```
color_red = np.repeat('red', red_df.shape[0])
```

I understand in `np.repeat`  the first parameter is the input array "red", The second parameter is repeats for each element, `red_df.shape[0]`.

if `np.repeat(3, 4)` the return would be `array([3, 3, 3, 3])`.

Anybody able to set me in the right thought direction?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's impossible to answer your question absolutely correctly without knowledge about `red_df`. I could only suppose that it's a `pandas.DataFrame` of unknown shape and data. Can you supply information about it?

Answer (score 3):

Get into an interactive Python session with `numpy` and `pandas`, and experiment

Make a dataframe:

```
In [394]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.eye(3))                                            
In [395]: df                                                                    
Out[395]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Check its `shape`.  That's a `tuple` (basic Python object):

```
In [396]: df.shape                                                              
Out[396]: (3, 3)
In [397]: df.shape[0]     # first element of the tuple                                                          
Out[397]: 3
```

Repeat with the shape parameter is just like using the number 3:

```
In [398]: np.repeat('red', df.shape[0])                                         
Out[398]: array(['red', 'red', 'red'], dtype='<U3')
```

Pandas and numpy are running in Python.  So the regular evaluation order of Python applies.

Comment: Thanks, looking at red_df.shape[0] confused me. Its just a count of the number of rows, which equates to the number of times 'red' needs to be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

This part  `(red_df.shape[0])` just to return an integer with the total number of rows in the `red_df`  to create the new add column 'Color' with the same number of raws of its related `red_df` so, when we append it later with the `white_df`, it doesn't shift down the other `white_df` and creatw empty rows on the other columns.

You can simply delete this section and write it like this:

```
color_red = np.repeat('red', red_df.shape[0])
color_red = np.repeat('red', 1599)
```

Full program will be

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_red = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv',sep=';')

df_white = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv',sep=';')

print(df_red.info())

print(df_red.shape[0])

# shape[0} refer to the number of columns which is 1599 shape[1] refer to the number of rows which is 12

# create color array for red dataframe
color_red = np.repeat('red', 1599)

# create color array for white dataframe
color_white = np.repeat('white', df_white.shape[0])


df_red['color'] = color_red

df_white['color'] = color_white

#combine data frame into one data frame called wine_df

wine_df = df_red.append(df_white)

print(wine_df.head())

wine_df.to_csv('winequality_edited.csv', index=False)
```